# How to stick a submodule to a fix a tag?

Tags: git, tags, dependencies, git-submodules

Assume we have two modules `super` and `minor`. Module `super` depends on version `v1.0.3` of module `minor`, whereas `v1.0.3` is an annotated tag on `minor`:

```
        v1.0.3
super <-------- minor
```

Module `minor` is kind of "private", i.e. only a very small group of developers has write access and others only have read access. Module `super` is public.

Now I would like to model the dependency of module `super` to module `minor` utilizing Git submodules. Unfortunately I can't figure out how to fix the dependency to `v1.0.3`.

In addition, I would also like --- some time in future --- to fix the dependency to another version.

In all cases I would like to have that
... all developers "automatically" retrieve the module `minor` in the correct version.
... all developers --- but the afore mentioned small group --- are not allowed to modify this dependency (whereas this is a minor issue)

Any ideas?

Cheers,
 /nm

Answer (score 3):

First, submodules reference commits (SHA1), so the simplest way to memorize the right SHA1 is to go in your submodule and simply `git checkout v1.0.3`, then go back to your parent repo, commit and push that new state: since a tag is associated to a commit, you will push the fact that your submodule is associated with that tag.
The same process can be repeated when you want to adjust the tag of that same submodule.

Regarding the right to modify that submodule, one way to control that is to add an [authorization framework](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/auth.html) on your Git server: [gitolite](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite).