# What is a good Git development model for heterogenous applications?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-submodules

I would like to develop an application constituted of an `iOS` and an `Android` Application. In addition there will be a `Web` front end with a REST API and an underlying `Database`.

There will be a developer team for each module, say, one developer team for `iOS`, one for `Android` and one for `Web/Db`.

My very first idea for a setup was the following repositories:

```
myapp-adm ~ Project administrative stuff (e.g. FSD, project plan, ...)
myapp-ios ~ iPhone App
myapp-jvm ~ Android App
myapp-web ~ Web/Db
```

With this setup, however, I have the problem of managing the dependencies between the modules. For example, all modules depend on `myapp-adm` due to the FSD. In addition, the modules `myapp-ios` and `myapp-jvm` depend on the `myapp-web`:

```
myapp-ios <- myapp-web <- myapp-adm  
myapp-jvm <- myapp-web <- myapp-adm
```

I could solve this problem (partially) with Git submodules, but as far as I know one can't set up versioned dependencies within Git. Right (cf. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12813250/how-to-stick-a-submodule-to-a-fix-a-tag"How to stick a submodule to a fix a tag?"))? For example:

```
            v1.0.3           v1.0
myapp-ios <------ myapp-web <---- myapp-adm  
           v1.0.3            v1.0
myapp-jvm <------ myapp-web <---- myapp-adm
```

Besides this potential setup utilizing Git submodules, I wonder if there isn't another "one-repository" approach utilizing Git branches. For example:

```
origin/master  ~ HEAD reflects production-ready state.
origin/dev-ios ~ HEAD reflects the latest iOS development changes for the next release
origin/dev-jvm ~ ...
origin/dev-web ~ ...
```

The problem I have here is, that the `iOS` development depends on the `web` development, but the web developers commit to `origin/dev-web`. The same holds for `jvm`. So that's not really a solution.

Or would you suggest that, e.g., the `iOS` developer team continuously has to merge from `origin/dev-web`?

Any hints/ advices are appreciated.

Cheers,
 /nm

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest having better boundaries between your web app and your mobile apps than that. In other words, your mobile apps shouldn't be tightly tied to a specific version of your web app; you should have a properly versioned and backwards-compatible API that they use.

With that in place, it's trivial to simply keep the apps in separate repositories.

Comment: Can you elaborate your suggestion a bit more? If I understood you correctly, you suggest, e.g., one repository for iOS & Android App and one for the Web App. In addition the mobile Apps should /not/ strongly depend on the Web API. In addition the Web API must be backwards-compatible. Is this feasible during the development process? After the first public release, I totally concur. Last, what exactly do you mean with `properly versioned`. In short, I would highly appreciate a simple example. Thanks for your reply! Cheers, /nm

Comment: You don't necessarily need to enforce backwards compatibility during the development process, but you are correct that the mobile apps should *not* be strongly connected to the web *code*. They should use the API, but only through the defined API endpoints (and thus they shouldn't care about how those endpoints are implemented, as long as the endpoints do what they're supposed to).

Comment: "Properly versioned" means that if you make changes to the API, you increment a version number and keep supporting the old API for at least a version or two ago so that users can transition to the new API without their app breaking in the process.